# Difference between FosUserBundle and SonataBundle

Tags: symfony

What is the difference between FosUserBundle and SonataBundle?

Comment: Read up on them and figure this out on your own?

Answer (score 1):

FosUserBundle is a Bundle to handle user accounts made by FriendsOfSymfony. It is a part of SonataBundle - set of Bundles that also has well looking admin bundles and more.

That two Bundles are not replaceable, FosUserBundle is a part of SonataBundle set.